# Minima and maxima of a trig function

Tags: trigonometry

let $f(x) = \sqrt {4\sin^4x - \sin^2x\cos^2x + 4\cos^4x}$

what is the product of the minimum and maximum value of the function?

I tried turning them all to $\sin x$

$-\sin^2x\cos^2x = \sin^4x-\sin^2x ; 4\cos^4x = (1-\sin^2x)^2 = 4sin^4x - 4sin^2x +4 $

which gives us :

$9\sin^4x - 2\sin^2x +4$

then i dont know how to proceed

EDIT:

The equation above is wrong, i got if you try solving for the ones i have given :

$9\sin^4x - 5\sin^2x +4$

then I tried making $sin^2x = a$ (Thanks @Greninja for the info)

where in the the min is when $a = 5/18$ and the value is 47/36,

then the max is when $a=1$ and the value is 8

Min x Max = $12\sqrt{94}$ which looks far fetched

I dont know where I went wrong with my solution Please help.

And yes, I have been told that the answer is $\sqrt{7}$

Comment: Hint: try to find $f(x)=\sqrt{a+b*\cos(4x)}$ it is easier to find min and max.

Comment: Are you new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Use Indentity $$\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x = (\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)^2-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x = 1-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$$

So let $$y = \sqrt{4(\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x)-\sin^2 x\cos^2 x} = \sqrt{4-9\sin^2 x\cos^2 x} = \sqrt{4-\frac{9\sin^2(2x)}{4}}$$

Now use  $0 \leq \sin^2(2x)\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

The expression you should get is  $\sqrt{9(\sin x ) ^4-9(\sin x ) ^2+4}$
$$\sqrt{9(\sin^4 x -\sin^2 x) +4}$$
$$\sqrt{9((\sin^2 x - \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4})+4}$$
$$\sqrt{9(\sin^2 x-\frac{1}{2})^2+ \frac{7}{4}}$$
Now using range and domain of $sin^2 x $ get your answer

Edit1: now you would get the desired answer.

Comment: wait where'd the 9 go

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Comment: wont you put sin^2x as 1/9? in other news and i got wrong  and I edited the equation it must be -5(sinx^2) sorry.

Comment: For maximum value put sin²x =1 and for minimum value put sin²x=1/2 . By the way is the expression you got correct because the answers others got can never really match that of mine if your derived expression is correct

Comment: Oh wait where did i go wrong with my solution in the derivation part

Comment: I computed for it again i got -5 as the 2nd terms coefficient

Comment: The second coefficient must be -9 not -5 check again. So we get √7/2 as minimum value and 2 as maximum value.

Comment: Ok i got it now 4(1−sin^2x)^2 = 4sin^4x−8sin^2x+4. Thanks problem is complete

Answer (score 0):

First I wrote

$$4 \sin^4 x+4 \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x \cos^4 x=9 \cos ^4 x-9 \cos ^2 x+4$$
Then remembering that $\cos 4x =8 \cos ^4 x-8 \cos ^2 x+1$

I got 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{4 \sin ^4 x-\sin ^2 x \cos ^2 x +4 \cos ^4 x}= \frac{\sqrt{9 \cos 4 x+23}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{9 \sin 4 x}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{9 \cos 4 x+23}}$$
and 
$$f''(x)=-\frac{9 (92 \cos 4 x+9 (\cos 8 x+3))}{\sqrt{2} (9 \cos 4 x+23)^{3/2}}$$
Setting $f'(x)=0$ I got $\sin 4x=0\to 4x=k\pi\to x=+k\pi/4,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Plugging in the second derivative

$f''(\pi/4)=\frac{18}{\sqrt{7}}>0$ therefore $x=\pi/4$ is a point of minimum where $f(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$

$f''(0)=-9/2$ so $x=0$ is a maximum and $f(0)=2$

So the product is $2\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}=\sqrt{7}$

Hope this can be useful

Comment: why all the derivating stuff and all ? minimum is when cos(4x)=-1 and maximum when cos(4x)=+1.

Comment: what does f" stand for?

Comment: f(x) denotes a function of x

Comment: @zwin You didn't collide with "proof-nazies" yet, did you?